# "Соловей" и "слава" — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Правда ли, что слова *соловей* и *слава* являются однокоренными?

Comment: А откуда у Вас такая версия? Может быть, Вы расскажете нам в дополнении к вопросу? Кроме того, если Вы обратитесь онайн к самому популярному (школьному) словарю Шанского, то увидите, что соловей - от слова "соловый" (серый), а слава - от глагола "слыть". Или Вы считаете эти сведения неверными. Поделитесь с нами, пожалуйста, своими мыслями.

Comment: @Sharon https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/slovo_o_polku_igoreve/848/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Я думаю, что это художественное сравнение, использование созвучия. Посмотрела соловья у Черных. У него др.-рус. соловий и ст.-сл. и др.-рус. книжн. - славии. Он придерживается версии "соловей от "соловый". причем соловый - это не только желтоватый, но еще и вялый, сонный (ср. соловеть).

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы Вы в  своих вопросах  говорили  подробнее о тех проблемах, которые Вам трудно решить самому, вот хотя бы прокомментировали текст, на который даете ссылку. Тогда Ваши вопросы вызывали бы больший интерес у участников форума.

Comment: А что было раньше, "славий" (= соловей) или "соловый"? Вот ещё любопытный источник: https://books.google.ru/books?id=oQJTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=C7quvtA1ev&sig=ACfU3U3b6HCD8_glpro3TkZWpHjlNy2I9A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDloyilqLgAhUCXSwKHV1RDyoQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false А созвучие - да, исключительно навязчивое: "соловей российский, славный птах" (любопытно, знаком ли был автору "славий") и т. п.

Comment: Ну если птицу назвали по внешнему виду, то слово  "соловый" первично. Черных выделяет там о.-с. основу и и.-е корень. Правда, в статье есть еще материал о том, что соловьи и дрозды очень похожи, и у славян соловьями могли изначально называться "прыгучие" дрозды. Тогда соловьи   от и.-е. корня sel - прыгать.

Comment: сродни врабий - воробей

Answer (score 1):

Соловей
«Праслав. *solvijь, производное от *solvъ «желтовато-серый»; см. соловый, солово́й. Родственно др.-прусск. salowis «соловей», которое относится к слав. *solvijь, как др.-русск. жеравль — к лит. gérvė «журавль».» [CФ]
«Маленькая певчая перелетная птица сем. дроздовых, с серовато-бурым оперением, отличающаяся красивым пением.» [МАС]
М. Фасмер вводит  читателя в заблуждение. Цвет оперения соловья буро-серый, но это не главное. Смысл наименования соловья в его способности петь, исполнять рулады, славить.
Англ. nightingale "соловей" - ночной певец > nochkanij-glas – ночьканый глас (слав.)
Латинский термин «соловей»:
Неверная трактовка Luscinia  однокоренное с luscus – «слепой», «одноглазый».
Luscinia megarhynchos > luzgania/schelcania mrachnoj noch – лузганный/щелканный мрачной ночи (слав.)(редукция z/s, g/c; перест. l/sc, редукция sch/sc, перест. g/r, редукция k/g ), иначе, щёлкающий в тёмной ночи, где «лузгание» и «щёлкание» синонимы.
Не путать с Lucinia – светлый (лат.) – luchinia – лучинный (слав.)(редукция ch/c) 
Соловьи поют поздно вечером и на рассвете в мае-июне.
В слове «соловей» нет понятия сольного исполнения от «соло», однако, соловей, иначе, славий, т.е. славящий, отсюда имя «СЛАВИША» на гуслях, найденное в Пскове при раскопках, видимо, относится к гусляру.
«Щёкот славий успе» [Слово о полку Игореве]
Преобразования иностранных слов и латинских терминов делается по методике поиска славянских слов в иностранных словах. http://www.tezan.ru/metod.htm